# Не мигрирует django: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

При миграций (python manage.py migrate photologue) вылезает следующия ошибка

```
(cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding' )
```

Версия Django 3.1
Pillow 6.2.1
Django-sortedm2m 3.0.0
Вот код settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'qkpjp8i3*9wuec4ye@u7%zo2(@9@m55026s#z2=g($l#8&=e2n'
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'shop',
    'photologue',
    'sortedm2m',
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testirovanie.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testirovanie.wsgi.application'
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/photologue/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'photologue')

STATICFILES_DIRS =(

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_dev'),

)
```

код urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('^photologue/', include('photologue.urls', namespace='photologue')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Всё правильно, в Django 3.1 не существует никакого python_2_unicode_compatible, и из всех ваших файлов его нужно стереть

Comment: А как его найти не подскажите?

Comment: Помогло деграунт до 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"python_2_unicode_compatible" - какая-то из библиотек не совместима с django 3, обновите все до последних версий, если не поможет, то только даунгрейд до django 2.2